# iOS: Remove default drawing of UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitextfield

I'm trying to create a custom text field with a suffix, and I override the `draw(CGRect)` method to do this. I want both the text and the suffix to align center. Calculating and drawing them works as I want, however, the default text is still there and it overlaps with my newly drawn texts. So I want to completely remove the default drawing of `UITextField`.
[image]

Here is my implementation:

```
class SuffixTextField: UITextField {
    
    private let suffix: String
    private let suffixAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]
    private let spacing: CGFloat
    
    /// Create a text field with suffix text
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - suffix: The suffix text
    ///   - suffixAttributes: Attributes to apply to the suffix
    ///   - spacing: Spacing between the content and the suffix
    init(suffix: String, suffixAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any], spacing: CGFloat) {
        self.suffix = suffix
        self.suffixAttributes = suffixAttributes
        self.spacing = spacing
        
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        
        addTarget(self,
                  action: #selector(textFieldDidChange),
                  for: UIControl.Event.editingChanged)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        guard !suffix.isEmpty else {
            super.draw(rect)
            return
        }

        let text = (self.text ?? "") as NSString
        let textSize = text.size(withAttributes: typingAttributes)
        let fieldSize = frame.size
        let suffixSize = (suffix as NSString).size(withAttributes: suffixAttributes)

        func drawSuffix(xPosition: CGFloat) {
            let suffixYPosition = (fieldSize.height / 2) - (suffixSize.height / 2)
            let rect = CGRect(origin: .init(x: xPosition, y: suffixYPosition),
                              size: suffixSize)
            (suffix as NSString).draw(in: rect, withAttributes: suffixAttributes)
        }

        switch textAlignment {
        case .left:
            super.draw(rect)
            drawSuffix(xPosition: textSize.width + spacing)
        case .center:
            let textXPosition = (fieldSize.width - textSize.width - spacing - suffixSize.width) / 2
            let textYPosition = (fieldSize.height - textSize.height) / 2
            text.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .init(x: textXPosition, y: textYPosition), size: textSize),
                      withAttributes: typingAttributes)

            let suffixXPosition = textXPosition + textSize.width + spacing
            drawSuffix(xPosition: suffixXPosition)
        default:
            fatalError("Cannot handle other allignment, please implement here")
        }
    }
    
    @objc private func textFieldDidChange() {
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call `super.draw(rect)` and draw your own text as textfield will always draw its text by itself. What you can do is that you can place your suffix text accordingly and it will work.

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    guard !suffix.isEmpty else {
        return
    }

    let text = (self.text ?? "") as NSString
    let textSize = text.size(withAttributes: typingAttributes)
    let fieldSize = frame.size
    let suffixSize = (suffix as NSString).size(withAttributes: suffixAttributes)

    func drawSuffix(xPosition: CGFloat) {
        let suffixYPosition = (fieldSize.height / 2) - (suffixSize.height / 2)
        let rect = CGRect(origin: .init(x: xPosition, y: suffixYPosition),
                          size: suffixSize)
        (suffix as NSString).draw(in: rect, withAttributes: suffixAttributes)
    }

    switch textAlignment {
    case .left:
        drawSuffix(xPosition: textSize.width + spacing)
    case .center:
        let textXPosition = (fieldSize.width - textSize.width - spacing - suffixSize.width) / 2
        let suffixXPosition = textXPosition + textSize.width + spacing
        drawSuffix(xPosition: suffixXPosition)
    default:
        fatalError("Cannot handle other allignment, please implement here")
    }
}
```

Comment: I did this before, but the problem is that now if I set it to center, the texts won't align at center anymore but skewed to the right instead.